# PowerShell string replacement

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to build a PowerShell script such that I give it an input file and regex, it replaces the matching content with the environment variable.

For example, if the input file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/Services" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="IntegrationManager_PartitionCount" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="IntegrationManager_MinReplicaSetSize" Value="2" />
      <Parameter Name="IntegrationManager_TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="#{INT_MGR_IC}" />
      <Parameter Name="EventManager_InstanceCount" Value="#{EVT_MGR_IC}" />
      <Parameter Name="Entities_InstanceCount" Value="#{ENT_IC}" />
      <Parameter Name="Profile_InstanceCount" Value="#{PRF_IC}" />
      <Parameter Name="Identity_InstanceCount" Value="#{IDNT_IC}" />
   </Parameters>
</Application>
```

I would like to build a script that replaces `#{INT_MGR_IC}` with the value of the `INT_MGR_IC` environment variable and so on.

Specifically, I am interested to know how to:

1. Extract and loop over keys from the file such as: `#{INT_MGR_IC}`, `#{EVT_MGR_IC}`, etc.
2. Once I have the key, how do I replace it with an associated environment variable. For example, `#{INT_MGR_IC}` with `INT_MGR_IC` env. variable.

### Update

This is the RegEx I am planning to use: `/#{(.+)}/g`

Comment: What you mean loop over keys? loop over each parameter?

Comment: @jisaak: Correct, 1. Extract all the strings that are enclosed within `#{` and `}` ... and then replace them with associated ENV variable.

Comment: OK guys, before you start voting to close the question, please ask me if you are having difficulties understanding the question! I think this is a valid question. At least, this is the valid problem I am trying to solve at work. I am sure someone, somewhere will also benefit -- especially when it comes to config file transformations in the automated build/deploy process.

Comment: Okay, I will try to provide you are script. But not using regex, read why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1163423

Comment: @jisaak: Thanks a lot for the quick response and link. I am going through it. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet, iterate over each `Parmeter`, filter all parameter that `Value` starts with an `#`using [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) and change the value. Finally, use the [Set-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113392) cmdlet to write it back:

```
$contentPath = 'Your_Path_Here'
$content = [xml] (Get-Content $contentPath)
$content.DocumentElement.Parameters.Parameter | Where Value -Match '^#' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Value = "REPLACE HERE"
}
$content | Set-Content $contentPath
```

In case you need to determine an environment variable, you could use `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($_.Value)`.

Comment: Thank you. I am giving it a try.

Comment: I guess instead of a `^#` regex you could use `.StartsWith('#')`

Comment: Yeah, but it would require to use curly brackets and `$_.Value` notation. But would still be more readable - I agree. Another one:  `Where { $_.Value[0] -eq '#' }`.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for everyone who helped. Especially, `@jisaak` :)

---

Here is the final script I built that solved the problem in the question. Hopefully its useful to someone!

```
$configPath = 'Cloud.xml'
$config = [xml] (Get-Content $configPath)
$config.DocumentElement.Parameters.Parameter |  Where {$_.Value.StartsWith("#{")} | ForEach-Object {
    $var = $_.Value.replace("#{","").replace("}","")
    $val = (get-item env:$var).Value
    Write-Host "Replacing $var with $val"
    $_.Value = $val
}

$config.Save($configPath)
```